# socket for messaging between UI and C code?

Tags: c#, c, wpf, winforms, sockets

I have implemented a C library and would like to expose its functionality to a UI. The UI will either be a Windows Forms UI or a WPF UI.

To come up with a more "platform independent" way of tying the UI and the C lib together, I have thought about creating a socket on the UI side as well as on the C-side. The socket will be used for exchanging bi-directional messages between the UI and the library. I know that there might be some overhead to doing it in this way, but the "message traffic" between the UI and the C code is not going to be heavy.

Another reason for doing it this way, is because I've read that there are so many pitfalls that you have to be aware of when you use PInvoke, IJW, COM or CLI (for enabling C#-to-C calls and C-to-C# calls). This socket-approach makes it more clean and I'll have better control of what's actually going on when the C# code sends a message to the C code (or the other way around).

To get started and to avoid wasting my time, I'm looking for some advice from seasoned developers who know a lot about socket code.

I'm not sure about what the requirements for the socket code on either side should be? I do know that I want any component on the UI side to be able to send and respond to messages.

[image: UI communicates with C module through a socket]

Comment: Do you mean by 'sockets': network sockets? Maybe you can use Named Pipes. Named Pipes can be created on the C++ end and on the C# end. On the C# side you have `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipClientStream`. You access them by means of a `Stream` interface.

Comment: This _almost_ sounds like it should be on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not Windows Communication Foundation?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would just like to say the overhead of socket calls and serialization is likely to be much greater that P/Invoke. Sure there are pitfalls for P/Invoke, but there are for sockets too.

Comment: @joel: yes you're probably right but the messaging traffic wont be high volume/frequency....and the code will be "cleaner"

Comment: So what's wrong with P/Invoke exactly?

Comment: @Blam he said "platform independant".

Comment: You seriously don't want to use sockets for this sort of thing.  Platform independant is a misnomer and you will find lots of grief at the end of that path.

Comment: @peter: what can possibly go wrong by exposing c lib functionality through a server/client API?

Comment: You now have a dependency on the network, a driver, the existence of a card.  The configuration of that socket is now required. while "sockets" exists on all OSes, you're not going to have one piece of code that will work on all of them--you'll have variations per, leading to more maintenance.  If it's configured for network you'll have network traffic (and slowdowns because of it) where you didn't have any before.  You'll have data transfer objects and/or mapping back and forth form in memory to over-the-wire that you'll also have to manage.  etc.

Comment: @peter: so what would you do? Let's just assume Windows as the platform for UI and the C-lib

Comment: I would simply PInvoke the library.

Comment: @peter: isn't CLI the recommended way for enabling bi-directional calls between windows forms c# and a static C lib? i believe the "glue" is a c++ CLI DLL ? does that allow for bi-directional calls? and what do i have to be aware of in terms of pitfalls?

Comment: yes, managed C++ does all the pinvoke glue for you.  When I say "pinvoke" I include that.

Comment: how does c# treat a native ptr to allocated memory? say a c function which returns a pointer to a byte array.....will the garbage collector try to free the byte array ? probably not...but what are the serious pitfalls that i have to be aware of while implementing the "glue"???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61713/discussion-between-user1884325-and-peter-ritchie).

Answer (score 0):

Using sockets will require your c program to become a server, which opens a socket and listens. Upon receiving a request it does some stuff and typically returns an answer. The idea is communication between networked computers.

here is a basic example. http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Writing socket code requires compatable data formats between the sending app and receiving app. This means you need to carefully structure your messages and ensure that each integer, long integer, float, double and fixed length string exactly match. An extra byte on 1 side will scramble your message into junk. If your c and c# data encoding formats mismatch - you will have extra decoding/formatting work.

I preferred to use ONC-RPC to write client server code between inequal systems. A decade ago I used RPC to connect big endian Solaris to a little endian VMS system - it worked flawlessly, it was really quick to write.

I'd avoid writing low level socket code because it's time consuming and difficult, except when you need high performance networked apps.